# useLazyQuery is not updating data on refetch

Tags: apollo-client, react-apollo

I am using below code to get contacts from server.

```
 const [getAllContactsInGroup, { data: getAllContactsData, loading: loadingContactsData, refetch: refetchQuery },] = useLazyQuery(GET_ALL_CONTACTS_IN_GROUP, {
        client, fetchPolicy: "no-cache", notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true, onCompleted: () => {
            //alert("Completed")
        }
    });

 useEffect(() => {
        console.log('getAllContactsData');
        if (getAllContactsData) {
            console.log(getAllContactsData['getAllContactsInGroup']['contacts'])
            setUserGroupData(getAllContactsData['getAllContactsInGroup']['contacts']);
        }
    }, [getAllContactsData]);
```

when i call `refetchQuery` function the `getAllContactsData` is not set in useEffect. It is set when i run for the first time but not on the refetch.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Had a Similar issue with my code base as well you can use

```
{fetchPolicy: "network-only"}
```

inside your useLazyQuery(). It works cost network requests every time you trigger a fetch event.
You can also use

```
{ fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network" }
```

to make sure it checks for both cache and the network ( server )

Also, check out this [Github Issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/7171)